# (oracle 12c) pls-00201 error when make trigger with new.column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, database-trigger

I want to make trigger this is raising error when `emp.sal < 10`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sal_more_than_ten_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON emp FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
  sal_lease_than_ten_error EXCEPTION;
  BEGIN
    IF new.sal < 10 THEN -- error occured!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      RAISE sal_lease_than_ten_error;
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN sal_lease_than_ten_error THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'give me more');
END;
/
```

How do I compare new `emp.sal` with `10`?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the colon in front of `new`:

```
IF :new.sal < 10 THEN
```